# How can I give my android chrome access to my microphone?

Tags: javascript, android, microphone

My chrome of course has a mic permission but when I get the " wants to use your microphone" alert nothing happens when I choose allow. This happens when I use websites as well as local JS scripts.

I have Oreo android and an up to date chrome.

Edit: moved from superuser where it doesn't belong.